# How to show image of woocommerce product attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I installed [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin and added images to one of my attributes, but I can't get them to be shown in template. When I var_dump the $result of:

```
$result = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );
```

I get an empty string.

I can get the value of attribute by:

```
$product->get_attribute( 'logo' );
```

But there's only string, not an object.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) plugin allows to add Image support for taxonomy. WooCommerce Attributes is **not** Custom Taxonomy.

Also, verify you added above code in, taxonomy archive template. If it is used in, unsupported template file it returns empty string.

Hope this helps.